# IndexOutOfBoundsException with Priority Queue/ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, priority-queue

I am working on this project to do Dijkstra's Algorithm(It seems like a lot of code for this but I have to use other given classes and restrictions of the project) and I am using a priority queue which puts neighbors of the current vertex into the queue, which is prioritized by the shortest distance between vertices. It works fine for the most part but when adding the neighbor Coordinates to the priority queue(pq), once it hits 7 elements, it throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException in one of the neighbor.add() lines. The array of neighbors never passes a length of 4 and is recreated each loop so I don't think it is an ArrayList deletion problem. Am I doing something wrong with Priority Queue or is it in fact the array list? I am relatively new to using both of these so this is my first in-depth work with them.

I have tried changing the way the priority queue and ArrayList are created and where they are created/updated as much as I can and still have it function without changing the entire code. If I comment out the pq.add(nb) line then it does not have this exception which leads me further to believe that this is where my issue lies.

```
Comparator<Coordinate> compareCoord = new Comparator<Coordinate>(){   
     public int compare(Coordinate a, Coordinate b){    
          if(a.getTerrainCost() > b.getTerrainCost())     return 1;   
          if(a.getTerrainCost() < b.getTerrainCost())     return -1;   
          else                                            return 0;   
         }   
};   
 PriorityQueue<Coordinate> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(compareCoord);   

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Loop used to repeat through all the vertices   
while(!unVisited.isEmpty()){   
 //Set current vertex to next in PQ and add/remove from appropriate lists   
    Coordinate smallest = pq.poll();   
....   
List<Coordinate> neighbor = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();   
   if(r!=0)        neighbor.add(map.cells[r-1][c]);   
   if(r!=rows)     neighbor.add(map.cells[r+1][c]); //Line of thrown exception   
   if(c!=0)        neighbor.add(map.cells[r][c-1]);   
   if(c!=columns)  neighbor.add(map.cells[r][c+1]);   

 //Run for loop for each neighbor of vertex   
for(Coordinate nb : neighbor){   
   //Check to make sure the neighbor has not already been visited   
   if(!visited.contains(nb)){   
        //Check path length of the current vertex to the neighbor   
        int index = coords.indexOf(nb);   
        Coordinate n = coords.get(index);   
        int nCost = n.getTerrainCost();   
        int altPath = totalCosts.get(smallest) + nCost;   
        //If path is shorter, update variables and add neighbor to priority  queue   
           if(altPath < totalCosts.get(nb)){   
               totalCosts.put(nb,altPath);   
               prevCoord.put(nb,smallest);   
               pq.add(nb); //If commented out, program runs with no exception   
            }   
    }   
}   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at pathFinder.DijkstraPathFinder.<init>(DijkstraPathFinder.java:73)
        at PathFinderTester.main(PathFinderTester.java:294)

Line 73 is commented to find where exception is coming from.
```

Comment: The erroneous line contains `map.cells[r+1][c]`, so check the dimensions of this cells 2d array that whether `r+1` and `c` are causing this.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't actually think to look into that more originally but after 2 days I realized it was a miscalculation of the length of my grid coordinates. Thank you.

Comment: I have added that as an answer then, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erroneous line contains `map.cells[r+1][c]`, so check the dimensions of this cells 2d array that whether `r+1` and `c` are causing this